# Execute a Method

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Goal:
When you press on the menu button named "Delete" when you right click in a listView, the method named Test() should be executed.

Problem:
I cannot make it to be happened because I get a error messsage.

> Error    1    No overload for 'Test' matches delegate
>   'System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler'

```
private void lvw_bokade_MouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ListView selectedData = (ListView)sender;

    Passlista myPasslista = (Passlista)selectedData.SelectedItem;

    System.Windows.Point pt = e.GetPosition(this);

    if (myPasslista != null && !(System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this, pt).VisualHit is ScrollViewer))
    {
        ContextMenu myContextMenu = new ContextMenu();

        MenuItem menuItem2 = new MenuItem();
        menuItem2.Header = "Delete";

        myContextMenu.Items.Add(menuItem2);
        menuItem2.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(Test);

        myContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
    }
}



private void Test()
{
    MessageBox.Show("ssss");
}
```

Comment: When you get an error like this, the first thing that you should do is to copy and paste it into a search engine. If you had done that, then you would have found dozens of answers immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the signature of your method to match the delegate of `RoutedEventHandler`:

```
private void Test(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ssss");
}
```

The signature of the delegate looks like this, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventhandler.aspx):

```
public delegate void RoutedEventHandler(
    Object sender,
    RoutedEventArgs e
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your method needs to match this `delegate`:

```
public delegate void RoutedEventHandler(
    Object sender,
    RoutedEventArgs e
)
```

You need to change it to:

```
private void Test(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("ssss");    
}
```

Answer (score -2):

change the signature of the method test to:

```
private void Test(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```